# Usando regex en Twitterrific ¿como muteo todos los tweets de un usuario que no contengan un enlace?

Tags: regex, twitter

De un usuario solo me interesan los tweets que contienen enlaces, pues son artículos o noticias, pero no los tweets con opiniones personales o comentarios. Usando regex tengo ya varias reglas, pero no se como “dejar pasar solo tweets que contengan una url”.

Para ocultar los tweets que no quiero en Twitterrific, uso por ejemplo:

```
@usuario ::: ejemplo1
```

De ese usuario muteará todos los tweets que contengan “`ejemplo1`”.

Pero la idea es hacerlo al revés y con un enlace, es decir, dejar pasar solo los tweets que contengan “www” o “http” o incluso la palabra “vía” presente en todos los tweets que contienen un enlace.

Comment: ¿Qué intentaste? Por favor lee [la información de la etiqueta regex](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) y agregá los puntos que te pide en tu pregunta. El enlace para [edit] está al pie

Comment: Gracias y disculpa, soy nuevo por aquí. He modificado la pregunta intentando que se ajuste, no se nada de regex, lo poco que descifro leyendo alguna web que otra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para negar una expresión regular, no hay una forma directa, sino lo que se hace es buscar que coincida con el inicio del texto (`\A`), siempre y cuando "no esté seguido por un patrón". Y para eso, usamos una [inspección negativa](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp#TOC-Regular-Expression-Operators) (o *negative lookahead*), cuya sintaxis es `(?!`…`)`.

Entonces para que coincida con cualquier texto excepto los que contienen `www`, `http` o `vía`, sería:

```
@usuario nombre de la regla :: (?s)\A(?!.*(?:www|http|v[ií]a))
```

- el modificador `(?s)` permite que el punto coincida con saltos de línea.
- más información en [*Regular Expression Filtering in Twitterrific (iOS)*](http://support.iconfactory.com/kb/twitterrific/regular-expression-filtering-in-twitterrific-ios)